# Xamarin.Forms Shell how to inject multiple and different values ​to string in route navigation

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

How can any property be injected into a page that we navigate using [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation) With Xamarin's native navigation it is simple since you have to instantiate the type of the page:

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new HomeViewPage { x = y });
```

In Shell only lets me pass string values

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//home/bottomtab2?name={"Cat"}");
```

I am trying to pass a Boolean value and it shows me the following error:
**'Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Boolean'.'**

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//home/bottomtab2?test={true}");
```

And if you tried to send several parameters, none of the sent parameters work, is there a way to send several simultaneously?

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//home/bottomtab2?name={"Cat"}?test={"Dog"}");
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data

Comment: That page you linked has information on [passing data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data)

Comment: @Jason But it only lets me pass string values, I am trying to pass a Boolean value and it shows me the following error: 'Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Boolean'.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first when you pass the value in Route uri ,multiple parameters need to be connected with `&` not `?` like

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//home/bottomtab2?name={"Cat"}&test={"Dog"}");
```

second if you want to pass a `bool` type

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//home/bottomtab2?test={true}");
```

in your target page,you could receive it as a string,then it won't throw error，like :

```
[QueryProperty("Test", "test")]
public partial class AboutPage : ContentPage
{
 string test;
 public string Test
    {
        set =>test = Uri.UnescapeDataString(value); 
        get => test;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Uri.UnescapeDataString was what I was looking for the remove those pesky %22's!